# Excel VBAが度々ハングアップする

Tags: excel, vba

ワンボードマイコンでイルミネーションを点滅させるためのデータをExcelで作成し、動作をシミュレーションで確認しようとしていますが、ExcelVBAが途中でハングアップしてしまい、再起動すると正常に動くといったことが度々あります。
原因が分かりませんでしょうか？

[image: データ入力画面]

tはインターバル、データの０は消灯、１で点灯としこのシートをtxt形式で保存したものがデータになる

[image: シミュレーション画面]

Startボタンを押すと、Sheet1の内容に従ってセルを黄色で塗りつぶして動作をシミュレーションする
Sheet1のデータの場合、a1からa4がA1からD1と、b1からb4がA2からD2に対応し、１秒毎に横に移動し、折り返して３番目当たりでよくハングアップします

on clickのvbaは以下の通りです。

```
Private Sub Start_Click()

Dim maxrow As Integer
Dim maxcol As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

maxrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
maxcol = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To maxrow
    For j = 1 To (maxcol - 1) / 2
        If Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = 1 Then
            Sheet2.Cells(1, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Else
            Sheet2.Cells(1, j).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    Next j

    For j = (maxcol - 1) / 2 + 1 To maxcol
        If Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = 1 Then
            Sheet2.Cells(2, j - (maxcol - 1) / 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Else
            Sheet2.Cells(2, j - (maxcol - 1) / 2).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    Next j

    Sleep (Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 1) * 1000)

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: 元のデータの量(maxrow, maxcol)は、どのぐらいなんでしょうね。ループの実行回数はおおよそ maxrow * maxcol　になりますが、質問に書かれている9列14行ぐらいの量なら、計算にそんなに時間がかからないと思うのですが。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

質問文の「ハングアップ」が「応答なし」を指しているのであれば、単に`Start_Click`の実行時間が長すぎるのが原因です。この場合`Sleep`付近に`DoEvents`を追加すれば一応動きますが、他イベントの処理も開始されるため、例えばボタンを複数回連打できるようになるなどの弊害があります。